# I upgraded from win 7 to ubuntu 12.04 and know my html codes dont work

Tags: 12.04, html

Hello i just started using Ubuntu the other day i never used Linux or anything else besides windows before. I started learning HTML on windows 7 before switching to Ubuntu and know my HTML images are not working even after i made new images on Ubuntu and put the correct path and made sure the images are .png. After all that the site does not load the new images and the coeds are just fine i put my HTML files on cloud storage before switching to Ubuntu so its not the codes. Also i am using Mozilla Fire Fox.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the paths for the images. Ubuntu is organized differently than Windows 7. For instance, if your images are in a folder within the folder your code is in (I'll use Images as an example), it is called ./Images instead of Images.

Comment: Hello,Thank you for the fast response i just want to say that what you suggested is not working for me,so i thought i would show you my code that i am using to give you a better example of the problem. So i have a folder on the desktop called "html' and in that folder i have the note with all the codes in it, next to it is another folder called "images' in that folder i have my background image just to make the page look a bit better, so my  line of code looks like this, body background=/home/almassou/Desktop/html/Images/Background.png">

Comment: It should look more like body-background="/home/almassou/Desktop/html/Images/Background.png"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check your upper and lower letter cases in images and in path. Windows does not care if you type uppercase or lowercase, but linux cares.

images/Test.png = images/test.png on windows, but not on linux.